# Google Maps not showing any markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using the code for testing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// When map page opens get location and display map
$('#map').live("pageinit", function() {

$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(evt, map) {
$.getJSON( 'http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/json/demo.json', 'category=activity', function(data) {

$.each( data.markers, function(i, m) {
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker',
{ 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(m.lat, m.lng), 'bounds':true } );
});
});
});
$('#map_canvas').gmap('refresh');

});
</script>
```

For some reason, it doesn't display any markers and sometimes the map is blank too.

Any ideas why?

Comment: This is not Google Maps API V3 syntax, but some jQuery plugin. I have no idea what $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker',..... does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/json/demo.json does not return jsonp, so because of same-origin-policy you will not be able to get the response unless your document is placed on http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com

Comment: I've saved the data locally to a local json file and tried it but I still have the same problem